# MATLAB - Plot a Function Currently Expressed in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have a function expressed in spherical coordinates:

```
f(r,theta,phi) = 4*exp(-r)*cos(theta)*sin(phi)
```

I'd like to plot this in MATLAB in these ways:

1. R3
2. R2 Contour Plot (x-y plane or x-z plane or y-z plane)

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the conversion and plot in Cartesian coordiantes:

```
f = @(r, theta, phi) 4*exp(-r).*cos(theta).*sin(phi)
[XX YY ZZ] = meshgrid(x_range, y_range, z_range)
% R = sqrt(XX.^2 + YY.^2 + ZZ.^2)
% Th = acos(XX./YY)
% Phi = acos(ZZ./R)
% This is faster. . . and significantly more correct.  See the comments below.
[Th,Phi,R] = cart2sph(XX,YY,ZZ)
fvals = f(R, Th, Phi)
```

I like `isosurface` to visualize 3D data like this.  For the 2D slice through Z=0 you could use `imagesc(fvals(:,:,N))` or `contour(fvals(:,:,N))`

Comment: The conversion is a bit off, should be: `Th=atan2(YY,XX); Phi=asin(ZZ./R);`, but preferably use CART2SPH as it is designed to avoid numerical issues

Comment: Is there a less ugly way to do this?

Comment: @Amro : How could the above code be modified to use sph2cart()?

Comment: @nick_name: `[Th,Phi,R] = cart2sph(XX,YY,ZZ)`. Also looks to me you have volumetric data (ie for each (x,y,z) you have a value), so you want to use functions like ISOSURFACE and SLICE as suggested..

Comment: Thanks for the peer review @Amro.  I was a bit careless.  I've updated the answer to make it better.

Comment: @CarlF. When I try imagesc(fvals(N,:,:)); or contour(fvals(N,:,:)); I get a blank plot. Any idea what's going on here? It appears I can only  view one plane.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sph2cart()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sph2cart.html) to convert the coordinates, then use [`plot()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html)/[`plot3()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot3.html) to plot the function.